# Serialize BoundStatement cassandra

Tags: java, serialization, cassandra, datastax

I have a use case in which I want to **serialize Cassandra BoundStatement** and convert it to `byte[]` array and send it over the network and de-serialize it back to `Bound Statement` object.

I am using **Java 8.**

But the **problem is that** BoundStatement does not implement `Serializable` interface.

Is there any way I can serialize BoundStatement, sent it over HTTP and de-serialize it back to `BoundStatement`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialized `BoundStatement` then you also have to serialized `PreparedStatement`, `DataWrapper`, because `BoundStatement` uses both of them.

**Even if you are able to serialized `BoundStatement`, You can't execute it without the session that created it. If you execute the `BoundStatement` with other session, Driver will throw `InvalidQueryException`**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Tried to execute unknown prepared query : 0x0c245df8681f7dc939aba0c76164e4d3. You may have used a PreparedStatement that was created with another Cluster instance.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.makeRequestMessage(SessionManager.java:571)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:131)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
    ...
```

Comment: Is their any way I can get query back from bound statement

Comment: Yes, you can  with `boundStatement.preparedStatement().getQueryString()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it returned me prepared statement query and not query which is actually going to database, example ------> returned `insert into table(name) value (?)` but I want full query with values `insert into table(name) value ('RAM')`

Comment: You can't get the query with value from bound statement . You don't know the values which are inserting ?